# jquery-mobile link not working

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

Hopefully someone can help me. I have what seems to be a bizarre problem.

I am using jquery-mobile with php.

I currently have two pages setup in a mobile document. It is setup on the PHP side to pass variables with GET. When the page initially loads I get the main page no problem. The second page is a calendar which allows people to select a date by clicking a link which is passing variables. When you go to the calendar and click the link, it pulls up the new article on the primary page and everything seems to be fine. When you try to go back to the calendar, the date reverts back to the original date from the initial load of the page. I can click every date in the calendar no problem and it shows me the correct article on the first page, I just cannot get it to hold the date when it goes back to the second page. On the URL bar it updates the information with the correct dates when I go back to the main page. When I go to the second page it reverts back again.

As a note, the links in the calendar match the link on the fifth line of code below. The only difference is there is no # in there since it is going to the main page.

```
<div id="mainpage" data-role="page" data-theme="m">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Today in Masonic History</h1>
    <?PHP
    echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?new_month=$new_month&new_day=$new_day&new_year=$new_year#calendar' data-icon='grid' class='ui-btn-right'>Calendar</a>\n";
    ?>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
   <?PHP
      if ($no_file){
            $my_day = $new_day;
            $my_month = $new_month;
            $my_year = $new_year;

            $fqfile = "../"._getFile($new_day,$new_month,$new_year);
            $level = "../";
            include ($fqfile);

        }
    ?>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4><?=$title;?> </h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="calendar" data-role="page" data-theme="m">
  <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" data-rel="back">
    <h1>Calendar</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">

            <?PHP require_once("[HIDDEN]"); ?>

            <center><a href="<?PHP echo "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?month=&day=&year=";?>">Today</a></center>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Calendar</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try cashing the page and see if that helps  --- <div id="calendar" data-role="page" data-theme="m" data-dom-cache="true">   -- what that does is -- Sets whether to keep the page in the DOM after the user has navigated away from it. So basically it keeps it in memory rather than load it again

Comment: Thanks. That didn't work though. It seems to be all about the fact that the #calendar is added to the end of the url. I have tried using a pageChange script, for some reason that only works once though when I click the calendar the first time. When I try to click it again, nothing happens.

Comment: well im not sure then. what you can so is use ajax to deal with the PHP part instead of directly using PHP in the page